# VHDL - coding error of value outside the clock edge

Tags: vhdl

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all;
use ieee.std_logic_arith.all;
entity RAM_controler is 
port(
      clk_50 : in std_logic;
      clk_baud : in std_logic;
      main_reset : in std_logic;
      enable: in std_logic; --active high write enable
      in_data : in std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
      W_order : out std_logic; 
      R_order : out std_logic;
      Data_OUT : out std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
      Write_Address_OUT: out std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);  
      Read_Address_OUT: out std_logic_vector(7 downto 0)          
      );
end entity RAM_controler;
architecture Behavioral of RAM_controler is
type state is (reset,operation);
signal state_reg,next_state_reg : state;
signal write_address : std_logic_vector(W-1 downto 0):="00000000"; 
signal next_write_address : std_logic_vector(W-1 downto 0):="00000000";         
begin   
state_change : process(clk_50, main_reset)
begin
    if (main_reset = '1') then
        state_reg <= reset;     
    elsif (rising_edge(clk_50)) then
        state_reg <= operation;
        read_counter <= next_read_counter;
        write_address<= next_write_address;
        read_address <= next_read_address;
    end if;     
end process;

writecounter : process(clk_baud, main_reset,enable) 
begin
    if (main_reset='1') then
        next_write_address <= "00000000";
        Data_OUT <= "ZZZZZZZZ";
        W_order <='0';
        Write_Address_OUT <="ZZZZZZZZ";
    elsif (rising_edge(clk_baud) and enable='1' ) then
        W_order <='1';
        Data_OUT <= in_data;            
        Write_Address_OUT <= write_address;
        if (write_address = "11111111") then
            next_write_address <= "00000000";
        else
            next_write_address <= write_address+1;
        end if;
    else 
        W_order <='0';
        Write_Address_OUT <= "ZZZZZZZZ";
        next_write_address <= write_address+1;
    end if;
end process;        
end Behavioral;
```

Above code is describing RAM controller.

The part of making problem is "elsif (rising_edge(clk_baud) and enable='1' ) then".

Error : Can`t inter register for "Write_Address_OUT" at RAM_controler.vhd because it does not hold its value outside the clock edge

I don`t know why that point is error.

Is there anyone who advice to me?

Thank you!

Comment: Should be assignments in the last `else` also synchronous to the rising edge of the clock? And which synthesis tool are you using?

Comment: Your code isn't a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), declarations for `W`, `read_address`, `next_read_address`,`read_counter` and `next_read_counter` are missing. Note for example  you're assigning `write_address` on rising_edge(clk_50)  with `next_write_address` which is assigned on rising_edge(clk_baud).  There are other design issues as Bill Lynch notes you're also doing assignments of `Write_Address_OUT` for example on any event of `clk_baud, main_reset` and `enable`.

Comment: I am using Quartus ii.
Actually below answer  is helpful to me.
But i don`t know why last else is changed like below.

Comment: @Kim if you don't understand an answer, then post a comment below this with asking for further explanation.

Comment: Just to know: to make a minimal example of your code, just remove all assignments which are **not** assigning `Write_Address_OUT`. Then remove all ports which are not required anymore. This way the question will be useful for further readers having the same problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're coding sequential logic, it is wise to stick to a template. Here is one such template for sequential logic with an asynchronous reset, which all synthesis tools should understand:

```
process(clock, async_reset)  -- nothing else should go in the sensitivity list
begin
    -- never put anything here
    if async_reset ='1' then  -- or '0' for an active low reset
        -- set/reset the flip-flops here
        -- ie drive the signals to their initial values
    elsif rising_edge(clock) then  -- or falling_edge(clock)
        -- put the synchronous stuff here
        -- ie the stuff that happens on the rising or falling edge of the clock
    end if;
     -- never put anything here
end process;
```

So *enable* should not be in the senstivity list and it should not be tested in the same if statement as the asynchronous reset and the clock is tested.

The reason why your are getting this error:

> Error : Can`t inter register for "Write_Address_OUT" at
>   RAM_controler.vhd because it does not hold its value outside the clock
>   edge

is because the last three assignments in your code:

```
            W_order <='0';
            Write_Address_OUT <= "ZZZZZZZZ";
            next_write_address <= write_address+1;
```

can occur on the falling edge of the clock or (because you also had *enable* in your sensitivity list) independently of any clock at all. A logic synthesiser can't synthesise logic that behaves like that. If you stick to the template, you won't run into this kind of problem (and it makes you think a bit more carefully about what logic you are expecting the synthesiser to synthesise).

So, I would have coded your *writecounter* process more like this:

```
writecounter : process(clk_baud, main_reset) 
begin
    if (main_reset='1') then
        next_write_address <= "00000000";
        Data_OUT <= "ZZZZZZZZ";
        W_order <='0';
        Write_Address_OUT <="ZZZZZZZZ";
    elsif rising_edge(clk_baud) then
        if enable='1' then
            W_order <='1';
            Data_OUT <= in_data;            
            Write_Address_OUT <= write_address;
            if (write_address = "11111111") then
                next_write_address <= "00000000";
            else
                next_write_address <= write_address+1;
            end if;
        else 
            W_order <='0';
            Write_Address_OUT <= "ZZZZZZZZ";
            next_write_address <= write_address+1;
        end if;
    end if;
end process;
```

Though, I should emphasise that my code does not behave exactly like yours. I don't know your design intent, so I can only guess what you intended. If you intended some other behaviour, then you will have to implement that instead. My advice about sticking to a template is nevertheless important, whatever your design intent.

Comment: The code template is helpful. But, for a better understanding, you should also explain, why the code of the OP does not describe a register.

Comment: @Martin Zabel You're right. Having read Kim's comment under the question, I was adding that explanation as you were commenting...

Comment: Thank you. Helpful comment.
Is there any other reason why enable should not be in sensitivity list excepting what you point out?

Comment: @Kim Processes that implement sequential logic without a synchronous reset just have the clock in the sensitivity list; processes that implement sequential logic with an asynchronous reset have both the clock and the asyncrhonous reset in the sensitivity list. No sequential process should have any other input in the sensitivity list, because the output of a sequential process does not change when any other input changes (think about it - when the D input to a flip-flop changes, the output does not change).

Comment: @Kim ... Although you can mix combinational and sequential in the same process, this is only possible if the combinational logic is driving the D input to any flip-flop; you cannot have combinational logic in a sequential process that is driven by the Q output of a flip-flop, but is not driving the D input of a flip-flop. This is because any signal driven in a clocked process infers a flip-flop. So, if you try to implement logic on the Q output of a flip-flop another flip-flop will be inferred at that logic's output...

Comment: @Kim ... I am not sure of the your design intent, but if you were intending that the signals driven by your process were depending on the enable input combinationally, then you needed to implement this in a separate process.

Answer (score 0):

The final `else` in your code should actually be:

```
elsif (rising_edge(clk_baud) and enable='0' ) then
```