# Fixing statement not synthesizable since it does not hold its value under NOT(clock-edge) condition

Tags: vhdl, fpga, synthesize

```
--Signal declaration
architecture Behavioral of Traffic_Light_Change is
signal State_A: STD_LOGIC;
signal segmentA : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (0 to 6);
signal segmentB : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (0 to 6);
signal counter : integer range 0 to 50000000:= 0;
signal State_T: std_logic;
begin
-- Switching anodes
anode_switching: process (clk_in, segmentA, segmentB)
begin 
if(rising_edge(clk_in)) then */ Line 78 error */ 
    State_A <= '1'; 
elsif(falling_edge(clk_in)) then
    State_A <= '0';
end if;
end process anode_switching;
```

Hello I keep getting this error when I attempt to synthesize my code. "Line 78 statement is not synthesizable since it does not hold its value under NOT(clock-edge) condition." What am I doing incorrectly here that causes this to occur?

Comment: You're designing hardware, so the synthesis tool is inferring [registers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flip-flop_(electronics)) for `State_A`. Registers -by design- only work on one clock edge. If you want to do two actions in one `clk_in`, you have to create a second clock domain, running at twice the speed of `clk_in`.

Comment: @JHBonarius His description is correct and can be synthesized by some tools, but obviously not by his tools. You are describing a DDR flip-flop, which might be available in I/O blocks of some FPGAs. Most synthesis tools can not translate this code. Thus, you need to use a vendor primitive.

Answer (score 0):

Synthesis is the process of turning HDL code into hardware. Your code cannot be turned into hardware, because `State_A` changes on both edges of the clock. How would you implement such behaviour in hardware?

See [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35667149/vhdl-coding-error-of-value-outside-the-clock-edge/35667799#35667799).

Comment: So I read your post there, so how would I make State_A not change on both sides of the clock, can you give me a basic example?

Comment: Synthesising HDL code is like using a calculator or sat nav. You need to know roughly what the answer, otherwise you could come unstuck. You need to think (roughly) what hardware you want and then to write the HDL code to implement the same behaviour. Systems exist where signals change on both edges of the clock, but they are pretty specialist. Make your signals change on one edge 9by convention the rising edge). The answer I linked to shows how to write code to do this. If you're not understanding what I am talking about, you need to learn some basic digital design (flip-flops, gates etc).